# How does javascript handle `this` when doing property lookups?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a function that needs to take an object and call a method on that object. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how `this` is set when invoking a function.

Let's say I have this object:

```js
myObj = {
  x: 2,
  get: function() {
    return this.x;
  }
};
```

If I simply do:

```js
callbackEval = function(fn) {
  return fn();
};
```

and then invoke it as

```js
callbackEval(myObj.get)
```

This returns `undefined`, since `this` isn't bound. Obviously if I write this as

```js
callbackEval(function() {
  return myObj.get() 
});
```

then it returns `2`, as I'd expect.

But if, instead of passing a callback, I pass a property name, look up that property, and then call that function, I get mixed results.

Let's say I write these variants:

```js
propEval = function(obj, fnName) {
  const fn = obj[fnName];
  return fn();
}

propEval2 = function(obj, fnName) {
  return obj[fnName]();
}

propEval3 = function(obj, fnName) {
  return (obj[fnName])()
}

propEval4 = function(obj, fnName) {
  return (obj[fnName] || true)()
}
```

and call them like so:

```js
propEval(myObj, "get");
propEval2(myObj, "get");
propEval3(myObj, "get");
propEval4(myObj, "get");
```

then, in order, I get:

```
undefined
2
2
undefined
```

What's the difference between how the javascript handles these 4 variations? Why is `this` bound when we make the calls in `propEval2` and `propEval3`, but not in `propEval4`?

Comment: the parens "don't count" in #3, and they might even get discard by the compiler. #4 is an expression, via the parens, which decouples it from the direct object ref (into a free-floating function) that would have assigned _this_. In short, you have to invoke a method from the object in order to get auto _this_ binding to the owning object. Brackets aside, i like to think of a method's _this_ as referring to the variable to the left of the right-most dot in the call.

Comment: OK, `propEval4` gave me pause. 
If you have some time and are looking for a thorough answer... 

There's this excellent series of books "You Don't Know JavaScript" by Kyle Simpson. Free on Kyle's GitHub: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS. The relevant one is "this & Object Prototypes", #3 in the series.

Comment: because a bazillion people fought with this problem, function [binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) were invented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partial answer: `this` is, bluntly put, a function's argument. It's 0-th argument, hidden and passed to it in a special way (or in explicit way - with `call` and `apply`). There's also no methods, BTW, just functions that happen to be properties of an object. If you invoke a function this way: `foo.bar()` (=== `foo['bar']()`), you implicitly pass to it `foo` as its `this` binding. When you invoke it this way: `bar()`, you do not.

Hence: `propEval` - no object, no `this` binding.

`propEval2` - the classic example of invoking a so-called "method".

`propEval3` - the () are irrelevant here. With or without them, the expression is evaluated the same, with the member access operator and the function call operator having the same precedence.

`propEval4` - it *looks* like the one above, doesn't it? Hah! What it actually does is first, evaluate the expression `(obj[fnName] || true)`, then invokes the result. It might as well be

```
const someTemporaryVariable = obj[fnName] || true;
return someTemporaryVariable();
```

I think.

Answer (score 1):

`propEval1` when you call function `myObj.get`, myObj is being passed in as the 'this' context. When you call `fn` you're calling the function without a context thus using the enclosing context. Note context being supplied is determined by where the function is being called and whether theres a `.` or not.

`propEval2` and `propEval3` are the same (parens don't matter) since you're always calling the function as a property of `myObj`. `myObj.get` is the same as `myObj['get']`.

`propEval4` I haven't seen this one but it seems that with the || it evaluates the condition and then executes the return of the condition which will be a reference to the function resulting in something similar to propEval1.